# Is Piping Mandatory for Single Operator

Tags: rxjs

Should I always use piping in RxJs 6 even if there is just one operator?  For example:

```
observableOf([1, 2, 3])
 .pipe(
    map(num => num * 2)
)
```

Can I write this without piping:

```
observableOf([1, 2, 3])
  .map(num => num * 2);
```

Is this OK for a pipe with just one operator or it is deprecated?

Comment: No. You can call the function returned by the operator directly, like this: `const mapped = map(num => num * 2)(observableOf([1, 2, 3]));` This is done [within RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.2/src/internal/observable/concat.ts#L120) itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing RxJS 6 and RxJS 5 styles of operators.

For RxJS 6 and later, only use pipe operators.  Avoid using the old "patch" operators and the `rxjs-compat` package as it's only for backward compatibility and is deprecated.

For more info see:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: Thank you so much for the commenting.